# Docker connection refused on host 0.0.0.0 (flask)

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to run an example flask app on docker and connect to it from my browser. My dockerfile is below:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

I run the app with this command:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 myapp
```

The logs say:

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

And yet when I visit `localhost:5000/` in my browser, the connection is refused.

I thought that using the 0.0.0.0 host would allow connections from my browser to the docker container

Comment: Try `http://localhost:5000`. `0.0.0.0` is not a valid address, it just typically means "attach to all interfaces".

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately it still doesn't connect

Comment: Hello, how did your work?

Comment: Sorry @Tlaloc-ES, I don't think I ever figured it out

Comment: Thanks @C_Z_ I guess is about ingress redirect, I am looking that currently.

Answer (score -1):

Access http://0.0.0.0:5000/ instead from outside the docker. From flask documentation:

> host – the hostname to listen on. Set this to '0.0.0.0' to have the server available externally as well. Defaults to '127.0.0.1' or the host in the SERVER_NAME config variable if present.

Comment: Neither `http://0.0.0.0:5000/` nor `http://localhost:5000` will connect

Comment: Did you tried adding an expose statement in Docker, EXPOSE 5000?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. My Flask app listen on 0.0.0.0 succefully, I have the EXPOSE 5000 line in Dockerfile but... I get this exact error.